# New to JS - how to format professional js files?

Tags: javascript, formatting

Completely new to Stack Exchange. Trying to learn programming, so checking out various websites and their JavaScript files. When I look at them, the look like a complete mess. E.g. If I go to Airbnb.com and view source, then look at the JS file (toward the bottom), then open it, it's a real mess. Others I look at around the web are similar. Is there a way to format this code to make it neater? (hopefully automatically e.g. if I copy/paste it somewhere?)

Here's an [example](https://a2.muscache.com/airbnb/static/packages/homepage-2930e36250124361f33d24ae716ced1e.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way, beautify it with: http://minifybeautify.com

Answer (score 0):

Your Examplecode is minified. There are many tools (http://jsbeautifier.org/) and plugins for IDEs to beautify it.

Comment: Doesn't mean it will make any sense tho as the variable semantic meaning will be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Many site uses uglify/minify methods to load scripts faster.
You can use a js beautifier to generate more readable code, but you should know that after minify method many var names are shorter so the code will not return to his original form

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it looks like this is because it has been minified and concatenated.

To get started with JS I would recommend to start from books or posts. Also the structure of the files will change depending on the the frameworks you are using. It will be hard for you if you start learning about programming just by looking at the code of some random website.

A book I would recommend you to start with is this one :

> JavaScript: The Good Parts

There is a very interesting repo at github which contains a series of books that you can start reading to start understanding pure javascript which is:

> https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

If you want to read about a js framework you could start with [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) among others.

And finally although it may sound obvious you could just type "JavaScript getting started" in Google and you'll see plenty of posts to start reading and having a better idea of what JS is about.

After you understand it I would say that you can go and see in other pages how they are solving certain problems but I would not recommend to start from there.

Hope it is useful for you

Best